# how to make multiple level of list style

Tags: css

Refer to the attached screenshot; how can I force all nested lists from number to square style and then reset the increment number?

[image]

Here is the CSS and HTML code using the snippet for the above listing

```css
ol { list-style-type: none; counter-reset: item; padding: 0; }

li {
    display: table;
    counter-increment: item;
    margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 0.6em;    
}

li li {
    margin: 0;
}

li li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul li {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><strong>Use of the Website</strong>
    <ol>
      <li>You agree not to upload, post, distribute or transmit on the Site of any content which:
        <ul>
          <li>is perceived, by us (or by any recipient), to be misleading, inaccurate, libellous, unlawful, obscene, threatening, deceptive, abusive, defamatory, or objectionable; or</li>
          <li>violates copyrights or other intellectual property rights; or adversely affects the data, software or computer systems of the Company or the others or the performance or availability of the Site; or</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>You agree to indemnify us in full form and against any and all claims, liabilities, losses, damages, expenses and other costs whatever suffered or incurred as a result of any breach of your obligations under Clause 1.1, including, but not limited to, any claims made against us by any third party.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li><strong>Intellectual Property</strong>
    <ol>
      <li>You acknowledge and agree that the ownership of any and all intellectual property rights (including, but not limited to, copyright and trademarks) in this Website belongs to us or our third-party licensors. Accordingly, any part of this Website may not be used, transferred, copied or reproduced in whole or in part in any manner other than for the purposes of utilizing this Website, meaning that you may only display it on your computer screen and print it out on your printer for the sole purpose of viewing its content in connection with the relevant matter.</li>
      ....
```

Comment: Please also include your HTML and make a [mre].

Comment: can you post the code in codepen or fiddle

Comment: Read about counters here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters And you’ll need two. Can you show a little more context in the HTML? e.g. is the code you have given within a container?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```css
ol { list-style-type: none; counter-reset: item; padding: 0; }

li {
    display: table;
    counter-increment: item;
    margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 0.6em;    
}

li li {
    margin: 0;
}

li li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    counter-reset: item;
}

li li li:before {
  padding-left: 0;
  content: "▪";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><strong>Use of the Website</strong>
    <ol>
      <li>You agree not to upload, post, distribute or transmit on the Site of any content which:
        <ul>
          <li>is perceived, by us (or by any recipient), to be misleading, inaccurate, libellous, unlawful, obscene, threatening, deceptive, abusive, defamatory, or objectionable; or</li>
          <li>violates copyrights or other intellectual property rights; or adversely affects the data, software or computer systems of the Company or the others or the performance or availability of the Site; or</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>You agree to indemnify us in full form and against any and all claims, liabilities, losses, damages, expenses and other costs whatever suffered or incurred as a result of any breach of your obligations under Clause 1.1, including, but not limited to, any claims made against us by any third party.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li><strong>Intellectual Property</strong>
    <ol>
      <li>You acknowledge and agree that the ownership of any and all intellectual property rights (including, but not limited to, copyright and trademarks) in this Website belongs to us or our third-party licensors. Accordingly, any part of this Website may not be used, transferred, copied or reproduced in whole or in part in any manner other than for the purposes of utilizing this Website, meaning that you may only display it on your computer screen and print it out on your printer for the sole purpose of viewing its content in connection with the relevant matter.</li>
      ....
```

Hope you find this useful!